# How to toggle enabled state of widgets based on QcomboBox index

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using pyQT 4.8.3 in order to create a proper GUI for a QGIS plugin

There are three widgets in the form

```
my_comboBox , my_lineEdit , my_spinBox
```

Assume that comboBox has three entries

```
'combo_first_item' , 'combo_second_item' , 'combo_third_item'
```

What exactly I want is;

```
if 'combo_second_item' is selected, then my_lineEdit toggles state to disabled
if 'combo_third_item' selected, then my_spinBox toggles state to disabled
```

So, how can I toggle enabled state of widgets in the form based on selected string (or index value) from the combobox?

What should be the proper signal -> slot assignment?
Unlike QbuttonBox, QcomboBox does not fire SetDisabled slot

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a dictionary that maps the string to widget:

```
widgets = {'combo_first_item': my_comboBox,
           'combo_second_item': my_lineEdit,
           'combo_third_item': my_spinBox}
```

And a slot:

```
def disableWidget(currentIndex):
     widget = widgets[currentIndex]
     widget.setEnabled(False)
     # or anything else you want to do on the widget
```

Then you can connect the `currentIndexChanged[QString]` signal to this:

```
comboBox.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(disableWidget)
```

Alternatively you can use `currentIndexChanged[int]` and a list instead of a dictionary.

PS: If this is inside a class instance, put `self` accordingly.